# How does the word "cardinal" relate to "cardinal numbers"

Tags: etymology, meaning-in-context

> [Cardinal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number_(linguistics))
>
> In linguistics, more precisely in traditional grammar, a cardinal number or cardinal numeral (or just cardinal) is a part of speech used to count, such as the English words one, two, three, but also compounds like three hundred and forty-two

> [cardinal (adj.)](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=cardinal)
>
> "chief, pivotal," early 14c., from Latin cardinalis "principal, chief, essential," from cardo (genitive cardinis) "that on which something turns or depends; pole of the sky," originally "door hinge," of unknown origin.

What's the relation between the two?

Comment: Have you looked up the etymologies? Where? What did you see? What is still puzzling you? [Edit your question](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/185229/edit) to reflect those answers and we'll be able to help you better.

Comment: Answered [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28314/whats-the-difference-between-cardinal-and-ordinal-as-adjectives/28328#28328) already (by Cerberus).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cardinals are quite simply the primary, most ‘basic’ form of numerals.

Different languages have different categories of numbers (English has cardinals, ordinals, and a few repetitionals or multiplicatives [*once*, *twice*]; Latin has these as well as distributives; Irish has animatives; etc.), but if a given language has numerals at all, it will almost certainly have at least cardinals.

The other types of numbers are given names for what they indicate *apart* from numeric values: ordinals indicate an ordering, etc.

Cardinals, being the primary type, indicates just the numeric value and nothing else.

Comment: What do you mean with "animatives" in Irish? I have been trying to look it up but couldn't find anything with that term

Comment: @Jon I’m not sure if ‘animative’ is an actual term – I may just coined it for the occasion to match ‘multiplicatives/distributives’. They’re a specific set of numerals used to count/refer specifically to people and other entities considered animate enough to be ‘people-like’, sort of like ‘pair’ and ‘trio’ in English. Their forms are: 1 duine, 2 beirt, 3 triúr, 4 ceathrar, 5 cúigear, 6seisear, 7 seachtar, 8 ochtar, 9 naonúr, 10 deichniúir, [nothing for 11] and 12 dháréag (for other numbers, the cardinals are used).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/616793/2085).

Answer (score 0):

So if cardinal meant "something on which everything depends", then a Cardinal in the Catholic church is an important person who makes decisions, etc. A cardinal number is the basic number on which other numbers are based.

Comment: Welcome. Are you asking a question or giving an answer? Can you show that "something on which everything depends" applies when describing cardinal numbers?